# Doing Inversion Of Control with webforms aspx user control

Tags: asp.net, webforms, castle-windsor, aspx-user-control

- WebForms 4.61
- IoC is done using Castle Windsor

I have a legacy WebForms application that I am working on adding IoC to. I implemented constructor and property injection for Page controls as [described here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/10/19/modern-asp-net-web-forms-development-dependency-injection/) which basically uses a HttpModule to perform the IoC for Page.

I now want to do the same thing for any UserControls. However there does not appear to be a hook I can use to intercede the IoC for the user control via the page life cycle or elsewhere?

I don't want to follow the approach described in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507377/ioc-and-webforms-how-to-inject-properties-in-user-controls) post which advocates a super user control base class that has all the possible interfaces in it.

So any ideas on how I add IoC (property and constructor) to System.Web.UI.UserControl?

Comment: Who instantiates the UserControl? Looks like you need a factory in which you can inject your stuff. Castle has the option for property injection too if UserControl and the like does not provide what you need.

Comment: User control is instantiated via the usual page life cycle.